# Getting 'Undefined symbol for architecture arm64' error after switching from react-native-webview to react-native-wkwebview-reborn on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an app on React Native and I am using Windows OS. I built this app and when I tried to submit (with EAS) I got email from Apple with the thext below:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

The app is old and I am working on updates. It had WebView from react-native-webview, I changed the component to WKWebView and react-native-wkwebview-reborn.

And now I am getting this error:

```
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
┌─ Symbol: _RCTJSNavigationScheme
└─ Referenced from: -[CRAWKWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] in libreact-native-wkwebview.a(CRAWKWebView.o)
1040

❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

▸ The following build commands failed:

▸     Ld /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-gnavtiawokiilkhfsvxzptupfwxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ProjectName.app/ProjectNamenormal (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')

▸ (1 failure)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

    Ld /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-gnavtiawokiilkhfsvxzptupfwxa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ProjectName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ProjectName.app/ProjectNamenormal (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')

(1 failure)

Exit status: 65

+-------------+-------------------------+

|           Build environment           |

+-------------+-------------------------+

| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |

| gym_version | 2.211.0                 |

| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk        |

+-------------+-------------------------+

Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how

to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make

sure your project is set up correctly.

fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the

the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.

Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there

[stderr] 
[!] Error building the application - see the log above

Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xc
```

I have tried npx react-native-assets with react-native.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {}
        },
    assets: ['./node_modules/react-native-wkwebview-       reborn/ios/RCTWKWebView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'],
    };
```

Also tried this:

```
    NSString *const RCTJSNavigationScheme = @"react-js-navigation";
```

I am not sure that I have tried these methods correctly, but anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-wkwebview-reborn` is outdated (last changes in 2019 https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview/commits/master)

In `react-native-webview` [v7.0.1](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v7.0.1) removed `UIWebView`, so you need just to update this library.

```
npm install react-native-webview@latest
```

More details information you can here in docs https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/tree/master/docs

Comment: I updated react-native-webview, and it was built successfully. But when I tried to submit, still got the email from Apple with error below:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Comment: RNHTMLtoPDF.h and RNHTMLtoPDF.m files and some other files had UIWebView, I replaced them with WKWebView. Still it returns the same error, although when I search there is no UIWebView in the project.

Comment: Use `grep -r "UIWebView" .` for find all `UIWebView` dependencies

Comment: There is none. I am using Windows, so I tried to search with findstr, and it didn't find any. 
I have WebView from 'react-native-webview'. Maybe it's somehow related to this.